# Why is setting/getting login status on a cookie a terrible idea?

Tags: django, cookies

I was looking for the best practice to set/get login status and come across this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113660/how-to-set-or-get-a-cookie-value-in-django).

In the answer, Yuji suggested that setting or getting login status on a cookie is a terrible idea.
I am just curious why it is a terrible idea.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: because cookies are stored on the users pc, and that means the user can change it

Comment: As previously stated anything that is stored anywhere outside your own storage space is even more insecure, cookies are helpful but only for a non critical or sensitive data. But then again cookies are an overhead to requests, if you need to store temporary data in the user side prefer localstorage.

Comment: Thanks GertB. and @petkostas for your answers. Then what is the best practice to set/get login status? Shall we always check it on server side?

Comment: @killua8p yes... all the authentication work should happen on the server side. Just use the Django auth framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first reason that comes to mind is: cookies can't be trusted.

Now, Django does actually provide a system which stores user data in the cookie... [cookie-based sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions) ...they are not the default but the option is provided. Take note of the warnings in the docs - the data in the cookie is "signed but not encrypted" - this means the user (and anyone with access to that cookie) can see the data saved in the cookie in plaintext, but if they try to alter the data the cookie will be seen as invalid.

*(Note that all Django sessions use a cookie, but the other session types like [database-backed sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions) don't store the data you associate with the user's session in the cookie itself, the cookie is just a token)*

So, given that it is possible to safely store data in a cookie why do we say "don't do ever this" about the login state?

The main reason is because there is no point inventing your own half-baked login scheme when there is a standard, secure and well-thought-out authentication system provided with Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

If you need to know on the client-side if the user is logged in, the most common way is probably to pass a variable from the view into the template, eg `request.user.is_authenticated` and render some different HTML or write out a var into a javascript block.

In Javascript alone you could also check for the presence of the session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers given: Some people tend to use cookie blockers.

And if you clear your cookies while surfing, you can change your status.