# Why don't cookies work properly in Django?

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-views, django-cookies

I have to set cookies to save cart details in my project but its not working, when i test cookies using function

```
request.session.set_test_cookie()
```

Then it set cookies but response.set_cookie function is not setting cookies. I have tried this code.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        response = HttpResponse('hello')
        days_expire = 7
        max_age = days_expire * 24 * 60 * 60 
        response.set_cookie('my_cookie', 'Product Cart', max_age=max_age)
        return render(request, 'home/index.py')
```

and for getting cookis , this code is being used

```
def sport(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'my_cookie' in request.COOKIES:
            value = request.COOKIES['my_cookie']
            return HttpResponse(value)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Cookie not set')
```

It always prints cookie not set string, What can be the reason behind it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113660/how-to-set-or-get-a-cookie-value-in-django

Comment: i have already checked this question, how it can resolve my issue

Comment: You don't return your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating two different `HttpResponse` instances: one manually and the other one is created by the `render()` call and returned from the view.
You should save the result the of the `render()` call and set the cookie there:

```
response = render(request, 'home/index.py')
response.set_cookie('my_cookie', 'Product Cart', max_age=max_age)
return response
```

You should also consider:

- Using an extenstion different from `.py` for your templates. They might get confused with Python code files.
- Using [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) for your shipping card.

Comment: Thankyouuu so much, it solved my issue, thanks a lot :)

Comment: One more thing how can i use "dictionary" in place of my_cookie variable like my_cookie.item_count and my_cookie.price

Comment: Cookies are text only, they can not store dictionaries directly, but a session can do that. IF you need more information, open a new question with the new topic.

Answer (score 0):

You must return the object as shown below otherwise cookies are not set to a browser and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622793/how-to-set-and-get-cookies-in-django/76599637#76599637) explaining how to set and get cookies in Django:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    response = render(request, 'index.html', {})
    response.set_cookie('first_name', 'John')
    response.cookies['last_name'] = 'Smith'
    return response # Must return the object
```

In addition, [Django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/) can set the session id cookies to a browser without returning the object as shown below:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    response = render(request, 'index.html', {})
    request.session['first_name'] = 'John'
    request.session['last_name'] = 'Smith'
    return response # Don't need to return the object
```