# How do I access data from local storage in Django views?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

How do I access the value of key "store1" inside local storage in my Django views.py??

HTML, in Django templates --> index.html

-User will key in input and button will activate local storage function

```
<input type="text" id="firstID">
<button onclick="myFunction()">LocalStorage</button>
```

Javascript

-User input is saved in variable which is used to for local storage

```
var siteName = document.getElementById('firstID');
function myFunction() {
  localStorage.setItem('store1', siteName.value);
```

Answer (score 9):

LocalStorage is client storage in your browser. Your `*.py` files will be executed in server. So you can not access them directly. You can save them as cookie, or put them to server via ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

As Bendy Zhang has said you might like to use cookies.

**In Javascript set your cookie**

```
var value = "some_value";
document.cookie="key="+value;
```

**Then in Django Views use it**

```
key = request.COOKIES.get('key')
```

Now you have your key value in the varible you can send it as a header (in case of auth token) or another value which you might want to use.

See here for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113697/3904109